# How do I restrict data entry to 1 character, but use the value converter to allow the user to change the value?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm working on a WPF app using .NET 4.5.2. There's a couple of columns in a table which are bit fields (we're working with SQL Server). So, they're bool data types in C#. The columns in the database are not nullable. The spec requires me to display the values either as "Y" or "N". So, I thought I would restrict data entry in a textbox to 1. Here's the XAML:

```xml
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource EnabledTextBox}"
         Text="{Binding ClassRegistration.PeaceOfficer, Converter={StaticResource BoolToYN}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         MaxLength="1" />
```

And here's the Convert method from the ValueConverter I wrote to handle this:

```cs
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool passedBool = (bool)value;

    if (passedBool)
    {
        return "Y";
    }
    else
    {
        return "N";
    }
}
```

Pretty straight forward. However, in using it, the app doesn't behave well. If the value in the table is a 1 (true), then it shows up as Y in the textbox. I can delete it, which instantly makes it N. However, no matter what I do I cannot change it back to Y again.

How do I restrict the user to just 1 character, but allow them to switch between Y and N?

Comment: I think your approach begs the question, would using a drop list, check box, or radio options work better?

Comment: I'm thinking that the culprit is your binding of `ClassRegistration.PeaceOfficer`. When you say you delete "it" which instantly makes the TextBox show N, what is "it"?

Comment: Using a TextBox for a binary type choice is a lot of extra work when a radio button or checkbox would suffice.

Comment: @quaabaam I asked my manager if I could do that. He said no. The users are demanding that they enter either a Y or N using the keyboard. No dropdowns, radio buttons, checkboxes or sliders allowed.

Comment: @TamBui, I'm sorry I wasn't clear. What I mean is this; when the window first comes up and if there's a true in the database, it shows Y in the textbox. When I put the cursor in the textbox, the press the backspace key, it immediately replaces with a N. But then I cannot change N back to Y. It will only stay at displaying N.

Comment: @Rod: Remove `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a few interrelated issues here, though I must admit I'm not sure I'm following your question.

Let me just share some code first.  Xaml:

```
        <TextBox Text="{Binding PeaceOfficer, Converter={StaticResource BoolToYn}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                 MaxLength="1" />
```

Value converter:

```
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool result = false;
        string passedString = (string) value;
        if (passedString == "Y")
        {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

View Model:

```
    public bool PeaceOfficer
    {
        get => _peaceOfficer;
        set
        {
            _peaceOfficer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }
```

So:

1. As the one comment indicated, set your trigger to LostFocus.... it'll work much better that way.
2. Make sure you properly implement your ConvertBack.  That probably is where your issue is based on the description.
3. Make sure you implement your view model to properly do property change events.  You might have, but, just in case.

Putting all those together in a simple WPF app, I was able to get both Y and N to work properly.  Honestly, anything but Y will default/reset to N.